# Connection String loading From web.config file in ASP.net C#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have developed an ASP.net web application which interacts with sqlserver database.
For database related task like ADO.net. Connection string gets loaded from web.config file.
connection string loading code is written below

```
 public DataBaseCache()
        {
            CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
          //etc
        }
```

My web.config file is below

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=F:\ProjectApplication6-3\ProjectApplication\App_Data\ProjectDatabases.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now Problem is that if i save my Visual studio project file to other drive i need to change my connection string in web.config file in this example it is in Drive F.
Please guide me how to avoid this copy paste each time i save application to various drives and code does it automatically.?
regards

Comment: Just make it a relative path to the database file, as opposed to absolute.

Comment: sir a little bit elaboration please?

Comment: You are using an entire path to say where your database file is located. Instead, you just need to include directions on how to get to it from your project. See Path article on Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the database in the App_Data directory in your project and use:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBCS"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|ProjectDatabases.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When you move your project to a different drive/computer, and SQL Express is installed, your project should be able to attach to your database.

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500829/sql-express-connection-string-relative-to-application-location) is similar to yours and may provide additional insight.

**Note**
I added "|DataDirectory|" to the connection string

Answer (score 0):

change your web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DBCS"
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename={0}ProjectApplication6-3\ProjectApplication\App_Data\ProjectDatabases.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and then in your code

```
public DataBaseCache()
    {
        string rootPath="F:\";
        CS = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString, rootPath);

      //etc
    }
```

Comment: same problem if i change it to D: drive then i have to change rootPath="D:\";

Comment: You can set it from the global.asax.cs file. From within the Application_Start event call Context.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
or from elsewhere you may get it from HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath. Obviously you will need to recover the drive letter from the full path.

Comment: I found the solution my self it is just using |DataDirecory| instead of full path since |DataDirectory| points to Appdata folder and then u just need to use /databaseName.mdf after it.Hope it will be beneficial to u also

Comment: Good job. Will remember that for the future