# Relative ConnectionString Database (visual studio) Vb.net

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, connection-string

I created a database with VS2015 express when I use this connecion string :

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\example\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\materials summury\Rexnord materials summury\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True
```

The connection is working, but when I use this one :

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=".\ Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=true;
```

I got the message : the login failed. can you help me with this relative connection ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Express connection string: mdf file location relative to application location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500829/sql-express-connection-string-mdf-file-location-relative-to-application-locatio)

Comment: Thanks Thomas G but I'm programming with VB

Comment: I'll see if I can find something like this but in Vb.net

Comment: I thought it can be applied to your case because you use Visual Studio

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to do it In Vb.net

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectionString` allows for metadata like `DataDirectory` You can use `Data Source=[DataDirectory]Database1.mdf` to get the the project root. Using `DataDirectory` or it's equivelant symbol `~` you cannot go higher up then the the solutions folder itself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx

Comment: Thanks Menno Gouw, I used your solution but I got this error message :
a database with the same name exists or specified file cannot be opened or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Your database is probably not in the `App_Data` folder. You can set the `DataDirectory` by doing `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", your_path)`

Comment: Thanks for you answer Menno, the program found the Database but, it seems that there are another problem this is the complet message :
 An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\example\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\materials summury\materials summury\bin\Debug\ Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @xAminex Not sure about that, probably deserves it's own question but you might want to look for similar question on SO first.

Comment: Thanks Menno, I did but I didn't find any thing, I'm gonna post it