# How to set relative path to database file into web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, connection-string

I'm trying to set relative path of database file into my `web.config`. I have two projects: DAL (class library), WebApi application. My database store in `App_Date` folder in DAL. I want to set the connection string to `web.config` of WebApi project.

```
<add key="connectionString" value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|Data Directory|\DAL\App_Data\Taskstorage.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"/>
```

And this is another example:

```
<add key="connectionString" value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=~\..\DAL\App_Data\Taskstorage.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"/>
```

None of them is working. Could you tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try the following code to read your config file.

```
using System.Configuration;
string t=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"].ToString();
```

Comment: I did before asking my question. I get an error trying to connect to my database. This is what I get from `AppSetting`: `"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=~\\..\\DAL\\App_Data\\Taskstorage.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"`

Comment: please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500829/sql-express-connection-string-mdf-file-location-relative-to-application-locatio

Comment: Suddenly it doesn't suit for me. My database file is situated into another project of common solution. I need something like this one: `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\..\DAL\App_Data\Taskstorage.mdf;`